# Playsound when a player leaves and area but not when they enter

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've got a sound `paspawn` and want to play it when people exit an area but not when they enter or teleport into it. The sound should only be played once.

Comment: Play continuously, or just once?

Comment: Just once. `paspawn` is a sound that is just a voice clip.

Answer (score 1):

Well first I would set up a clock and make the following commands in this order:

1. **/scoreboard players add @a[x=,y=,z=,r=] play 1**
   (@a[x=,y=,z=,r=]  Is the location of where you want it at)
2. **/execute @a[score_play_min=1,score_play=1] ~ ~ ~ /playsound paspawn @p**
3. **/scoreboard players set @a[score_play_min=2] play 2**

This would play the sound one time when they are at the location and then it would never play the sound again. Hope this helps!

Comment: Will try this later, thanks. Looking at this it only ever plays the sound once. I want it each time a player leaves an area.

Comment: If the area could be describe as simple cuboid or sphere, just `/testfor` with inverte output would do.

Comment: I am having problems /testfor. It doesnt seem to turn off the comparitor.